# How to add my "print content" into a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently started learing Python.

I defined title and price.

Now I want Python to create a Text file and enter the content of "title" and "price" into the new created text file

```
print(title)
print(price)

fh = open("Price&Title", "w")
fh.write()
fh.close()
```

This code above didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `file` argument of `print`:

```
fh = open("Price&Title", "w")
print(title, file=fh)
print(price, file=fh)
fh.close()
```